# Proving geometry about altitude.

Tags: geometry

BE and CF are altitude of triangle ABC, and M is the midpoint of BC. Show that ME=MF

I'd like to know if my attempt is correct.
I let M be the center of circle O,

since  ∠BFC= 90 and ∠BEC = 90, I conclude that F and E is a point on circle O.

So ME=MF = radius of circle O

[image]

Comment: Correct, and well done!  I would have missed this.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thanks!

Comment: My God, This is an absolute slick way to prove this. Well done!